# Using an image tag inside of an anchor tag with JSX

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am trying to use images as links in my navigation bar with text underneath but for some reason I am drawing a blank how to put an image tag inside an anchor tag with React. React yells that I need a corresponding closing tag for image but there is one. I know it is something simple but for the life of me it is not coming to me.

I have tried closing it with /> and wrapping the whole div in a React fragment.

```
import React from 'react'

const Navbar = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/"></a><img src="someimage.png" alt="some image"></a>/></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Navbar
```

Comment: That worked. Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are closing `anchor` tag twice,

```
<li><a href="/"></a><img src="someimage.png" alt="some image"></a>/></li>
```

Correct syntax is

```
<li><a href="/"><img src="someimage.png" alt="some image" /></a></li>
```

This also won't work, you need to do this for images,

```
import someimage from './someimage.png'; //considering image in same folder, if image is in another folder put the correct path here

<li><a href="/"><img src={someimage} alt="some image" /></a></li>
```

Or the another way to use images is, if using `webpack`

```
<li><a href="/"><img src={require("./someimage.png")} alt="some image" /></a></li> //make sure image pathis correct
```

If you don't use `webpack` still you need to wrap image path in `{}` like,

```
<li><a href="/"><img src={"./someimage.png"} alt="some image" /></a></li> //make sure image pathis correct
```

[Reference](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files)

Comment: There is no reason not to use a string path. No need to import it.

Comment: @Sulthan Simple string path also won't work without `require` like I mention the another way, I have also attached a reference link, have a look.

Comment: Also one reasong of importing images is, if in case we want to use same image at multiple places.

Comment: I am not saying its not a good idea. I am saying the original would work. I have been using that for years. If the image is placed on the correct URL, it will load without problems, the same way it would load in raw HTML.

Comment: @Sulthan Thanks for sharing this, I was aware that in react to use images without webpack, we need to wrap image path in `{}` but not aware simple string without `{}` will also works.I will definitely try this.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax isn't quite right.

This:

```
<li><a href="/"></a><img src="someimage.png" alt="some image"></a>/></li>
```

Should be this:

```
<li><a href="/"><img src="someimage.png" alt="some image" /></a></li>
```